# description in arrow is not working in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd

Following is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
    x
    \arrow[rr, "f"{name=F}, bend left=49]
    \arrow[rr, "h"'{name=H}, bend right=49]
    \arrow[rr,"g" {name=G} ]
    &  & y
    \arrow[Rightarrow, from=F, to=G, "\alpha"]
    \arrow[Rightarrow, from=G, to=H, "\beta"]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the code I have written for some diagram.

I want to put `$g$` inside the arrow, not above, not below. So, I used the code "`description`". It is not working.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
    x
    \arrow[rr, "f"{name=F}, bend left=62]
    \arrow[rr, "h"'{name=H}, bend right=62]
    \arrow[rr,"g" description{name=G} ]
    &  & y
    \arrow[Rightarrow, from=F, to=G, "\alpha"]
    \arrow[Rightarrow, from=G, to=H, "\beta"]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

I want to have both `\alpha` and `\beta` to be of the same size (at least of similar sizes).

Can someone help me with this? If I put "`description`" after `{name=G}`, it is not showing any difference.

Why is the description not working?

Comment: Hi, I have seen your code but the bottom implications are distorted and I don't understand the reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

A few things:

- You only need two columns.
- To `name` the spaces above (and similarly below) the arrow, use `""{name=GA,above}`
- I added `phantom` lowercase `f` characters to the `x` and `y` so they have the same height and depth (which keeps the arrows even).
- If you want the vertical arrows to be closer to the curved arrows, you can use `shorten <=` and `shorten >=` with negative values. Note that the space after shorten is not optional. (Code at the bottom.)

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=2cm]
    \vphantom{f}x
    \arrow[r, "f",  ""{name=F, below}, bend left=49]
    \arrow[r, "h"',  ""{name=H, above}, bend right=49]
    \arrow[r, "g" description, ""{name=GA,above}, ""{name=GB,below}]
    & \vphantom{f}y
    \arrow[Rightarrow, from=F, to=GA, "\alpha"]
    \arrow[Rightarrow, from=GB, to=H, "\beta"]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

To lengthen the vertical arrows (or any arrow) you can use `shorten` with a negative value:

```
\arrow[Rightarrow, from=F, to=GA, "\alpha", shorten <=-3pt]
\arrow[Rightarrow, from=GB, to=H, "\beta", shorten >=-3pt]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I got it. My code did not have \vphantom{f}y. What is that used for? How did it affect? It also did not have columnsep. If I remove column sep, it is showing very small.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik aahahah don't worry if you use one day xy package. But, in some occasion it seems more simple instead of tikz-cd. And thank you very much for Sandy G because without your image I not can improved my answer.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, the `\vphantom` command creates an invisible character with no width and the same height and depth as the `f` in braces. When you use the `bend left` or `bend right` keys in tikz cd the shapes of the arrows adjust to the size of the “to” and “from” cells, resulting in unintended placement of labels and arrows that rely on those placements. So the `\vphantom` causes the x and y to have the height and depth of the f.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** Mine is done with `xy` package more complicated instead of `tikz-cd`....and thank you very much to **@Sandy G** to have understood the answer with your drawing.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[all,cmtip,2cell]{xy}
\UseAllTwocells
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix@R+5pc@C+2pc{
x\ruppertwocell^f{\alpha}
\rlowertwocell_h{\beta}
\ar[r]|{\scriptscriptstyle g} & y\\
},
\quad 
\xymatrix@R+5pc@C+2pc{
x\ruppertwocell^f{\alpha}
\rlowertwocell_h{\beta}
\ar[r]|{g} & y\\
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I will use it sometime :)